# Action bar menu font color change using appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have a contextual action mode, the text color of the action bar menu should be red in color. 
I am able to change the text color using

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyStyledActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarMenuText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@style/MyActionBarMenuText</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_half_white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarMenuText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_half_white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonOverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
</style>
```

It works in android 2.3, 4.1. but when i run the same in android 4.4. It shows the default black color

Can anyone please let me know, what is the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create folder res/value-v14 and add style.xml and do modification there

Comment: @RahulGupta . Yes I have added the styles there too. and getting the same issue

Comment: change parent=@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light to another one in v14 folder  and check it

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you..You mean to say I should have a different parent for that style in v14 folder

Comment: yes reason android actionbar supports in >14 api

Comment: hmm, that is also not working..

Comment: I tried this in styles.xml in values-14 folder <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

Comment: same you have to change Widget also

Comment: <style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title"> This is how I am using for widget. Anything else I am missing..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not the cleanest way to do this but to change the color of my action bar text I use HTML code in the java classe like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>"+Your Title+"</font>"));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Will it change the the action bar menu text color? The above line will change only the title color I guess..Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right... for the option menu in the action bar I use `<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FF6C10</item>` in styles.xml.

Answer (score 0):

please use below code its working for me

and still if you have doubt and its not working then tell me

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- <item name="windowBackground">@color/background_window</item> -->
    <!-- <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item> -->

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF666666</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried the same, but still no clue..Between thanks a lot for your fast responses.

Comment: just copy above code and past it in style.xml see what happens

Comment: No Its not working.. I guess its not getting used. But the styles which I have applied in values folder getting applied in android 2.3 till 4.1. Actually Its a contextual action bar and has 2 menus on the right corner(Select All| Share) the text of these 2 menus should be affected.

Comment: get demo project https://www.dropbox.com/s/f83gps101a6hs3r/StyleDemo.zip check wht wrong happens

Comment: I checked your code. It is working fine. But in my application, I am using appcompat library, to make the app support from 2.3 to 4.4. So I guess, there is some compatibility issue when i am using the same style in my values-14 folder.

Comment: ok appcompat library used for supporting version below 4.0 so in that uhave to change styles.xml accordingly like V11 make different styls.xml and one common folder values make seperate styles.xml